# setting state in axios.get(url).then() does not work when using react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, axios

While working with **React** and **Redux** I encountered this interesting observation.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {fetchBooks} from '../actions'

class Sample extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        /* Fetching from server */
    }

    render(){
        return(
            {this.props.books.map(book => <Book key={book.title} {...book} />)}
        )
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return bindActionCreators({fetchBooks}, dispatch);
}

const mapStateToProps = ({books}) => {
    return {books};
}

connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Sample)
```

When I implement `componentDidMount()` function with redux as

```js
...
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchBooks();
}
...
```

the state is updated and the render function is invoked.

However, when I use axios with promise, it doesn't work:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
...
componentDidMount() {
    const self = this;
    axios.get(__URL__)
        .then((response) => {
            self.setState({books: response.data});
        });
}
...
```

1. Does this mean you cannot mixin the two ways to set state when you use redux?
2. Or why does one method work while the other doesn't work when **redux** is used?

Comment: Note that *redux* state is very different to *component* state.

Comment: You have your answer in [jonrsharpe's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56758157/setting-state-in-axios-geturl-then-does-not-work-when-using-react-redux#comment100074093_56758157). You're confusing the redux store state with React component state. Changing `this.props.books` to `this.state.books` should be enough to prove it works.

Comment: True. Thanks @jonrsharpe and Emile. This actually does checkout. I had hoped that component state was propagated to redux state.

Comment: _"I had hoped that component state was propagated to redux state."_ That would defeat the purpose of Redux altogether. You can however trigger an action that takes a payload from your component, e.g. `this.props.setBooks(response.data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you miss mess with a `component` state and `redux` state. when you call dispatch function using redux:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchBooks();
}
```

It dispatches the action function and redux state updated. The redux state catch from component props by passing the first argument at

```
connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Sample)
```

when you call `setState` after get axios response, it update your `component` state not `redux` state. so, in that case yon may find your data from `this.state.books` not `this.props.books`. If you need to dispatch action function when axios get response.

```
componentDidMount() {
  const self = this;
  axios.get(__URL__)
    .then((response) => {
        //self.setState({books: response.data});
        self.props.yourDispatchFunctionWithPassingTheReponseData(response.data);
    });
}
```

more information about dispatch, please check out the [link](https://redux.js.org/api/bindactioncreators)